# How to create easy, medium and hard level for tic-tac-toe-game?

Tags: java, android, tic-tac-toe

Currently i'm creating tic-tac-toe-game in android

i'm successfully created game but facing some issues

Here is my code that i have tried so far

> Here is My BoardView

```
public class BoardView extends View implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener, ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener, Animator.AnimatorListener {
    private static final int STROKE_WIDTH = 10;
    private static final int SWEEPER_WIDTH = 20;

    private float[] gridLinePoints;
    private Paint gridPaint;

    private PointF[][] centerPoints;
    private Paint signPaint;

    private List<SignData> signDataList;

    private @Constants.WinLinePosition int winLinePosition;
    private Paint winLinePaint;

    private GestureDetector clickDetector;
    private OnBoardInteractionListener onBoardInteractionListener;

    private ValueAnimator clickAnimator;
    private ValueAnimator winLineAnimator;
    private ValueAnimator resetAnimator;

    private float signRadius;
    private float winLineLength;
    private float sweeperStartPosition;

    private Paint sweeperPaint;
    private int[] sweeperColors;
    private float[] sweeperStops;

    public BoardView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public BoardView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public BoardView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private void init() {
        gridLinePoints = new float[16];

        centerPoints = new PointF[3][3];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                centerPoints[i][j] = new PointF();
            }
        }

        signDataList = new ArrayList<>();

        winLinePosition = Constants.NONE;

        gridPaint = new Paint();
        gridPaint.setColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.holo_green_dark, null));
        gridPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        gridPaint.setStrokeWidth(dpToPx(STROKE_WIDTH));
        gridPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);

        signPaint = new Paint();
        signPaint.setColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.holo_orange_dark, null));
        signPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        signPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        signPaint.setStrokeWidth(dpToPx(STROKE_WIDTH));
        signPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);

        winLinePaint = new Paint();
        winLinePaint.setColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.holo_red_dark, null));
        winLinePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        winLinePaint.setStrokeWidth(dpToPx(STROKE_WIDTH));
        winLinePaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);

        clickDetector = new GestureDetector(getContext(), this);

        clickAnimator = new ValueAnimator();
        clickAnimator.setDuration(150);
        clickAnimator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        clickAnimator.addUpdateListener(this);
        clickAnimator.addListener(this);

        winLineAnimator = new ValueAnimator();
        winLineAnimator.setDuration(150);
        winLineAnimator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        winLineAnimator.addUpdateListener(this);
        winLineAnimator.addListener(this);

        resetAnimator = new ValueAnimator();
        resetAnimator.setDuration(500);
        resetAnimator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        resetAnimator.addUpdateListener(this);
        resetAnimator.addListener(this);

        sweeperPaint = new Paint();
        sweeperPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        sweeperPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        sweeperColors = new int[3];
        sweeperColors[0] = Color.parseColor("#0000DDFF");
        sweeperColors[1] = Color.parseColor("#FF00DDFF");
        sweeperColors[2] = Color.parseColor("#0000DDFF");

        sweeperStops = new float[3];
        sweeperStops[0] = 0;
        sweeperStops[1] = 0.5f;
        sweeperStops[2] = 1;

        setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, sweeperPaint);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        getLayoutParams().height = getMeasuredWidth();

        setGridLinePoints();
        setCenterPoints();
        setAnimationValues();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        drawGrid(canvas);
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if (resetAnimator.isRunning()) {
            canvas.clipRect(0, sweeperStartPosition, getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredWidth());

            setSweeperGradient();
            canvas.drawRect(0, sweeperStartPosition, getMeasuredWidth(), sweeperStartPosition + dpToPx(SWEEPER_WIDTH), sweeperPaint);
        }

        drawSigns(canvas);
        drawWinLine(canvas);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if ((!isEnabled()) || (clickAnimator.isRunning()) || (isAnimationFlagSet())) {
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        } else {
            return clickDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    }

    private boolean isAnimationFlagSet() {
        for (SignData signData : signDataList) {
            if (signData.isAnimationFlag()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void setGridLinePoints() {
        int side = getMeasuredWidth();
        float padding = dpToPx(STROKE_WIDTH / 2f);

        gridLinePoints[0] = gridLinePoints[4] = gridLinePoints[9] = gridLinePoints[13] = padding;
        gridLinePoints[1] = gridLinePoints[3] = gridLinePoints[8] = gridLinePoints[10] = side / 3f;
        gridLinePoints[2] = gridLinePoints[6] = gridLinePoints[11] = gridLinePoints[15] = side - padding;
        gridLinePoints[5] = gridLinePoints[7] = gridLinePoints[12] = gridLinePoints[14] = (2 * side) / 3f;
    }

    private void setCenterPoints() {
        float a = getMeasuredWidth() / 6f;

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                centerPoints[i][j].x = a + (j * (2 * a));
                centerPoints[i][j].y = a + (i * (2 * a));
            }
        }
    }

    private void setAnimationValues() {
        clickAnimator.setFloatValues(0, (getMeasuredWidth() / 6f) - dpToPx(2 * STROKE_WIDTH));
        winLineAnimator.setFloatValues(0, getMeasuredWidth());
        resetAnimator.setFloatValues(-dpToPx(SWEEPER_WIDTH), getMeasuredWidth());
    }

    private void setSweeperGradient() {
        float axis = sweeperStartPosition + (dpToPx(SWEEPER_WIDTH / 2f));

        LinearGradient horizontalGradient = new LinearGradient(0, axis, getMeasuredWidth(), axis,
                sweeperColors, sweeperStops, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);

        LinearGradient verticalGradient = new LinearGradient(getMeasuredWidth() / 2f, sweeperStartPosition,
                getMeasuredWidth() / 2f, sweeperStartPosition + dpToPx(SWEEPER_WIDTH), sweeperColors, sweeperStops,
                Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);

        ComposeShader shader = new ComposeShader(horizontalGradient, verticalGradient, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);

        sweeperPaint.setShader(shader);
    }

    private void drawGrid(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawLines(gridLinePoints, gridPaint);
    }

    private void drawSigns(Canvas canvas) {
        for (int i = 0; i < signDataList.size(); i++) {
            SignData signData = signDataList.get(i);

            switch (signData.getSign()) {
                case Constants.CIRCLE:
                    drawCircle(canvas, centerPoints[signData.getRow()][signData.getColumn()], signData.isAnimationFlag());
                    break;
                case Constants.CROSS:
                    drawCross(canvas, centerPoints[signData.getRow()][signData.getColumn()], signData.isAnimationFlag());
                    break;
                case Constants.EMPTY:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void drawCircle(Canvas canvas, PointF center, boolean animationFlag) {
        float radius = animationFlag ? signRadius : (getMeasuredWidth() / 6f) - dpToPx(2 * STROKE_WIDTH);

        canvas.drawCircle(center.x, center.y, radius, signPaint);
    }

    private void drawCross(Canvas canvas, PointF center, boolean animationFlag) {
        float radius = animationFlag ? signRadius : (getMeasuredWidth() / 6f) - dpToPx(2 * STROKE_WIDTH);

        canvas.drawLine(center.x - radius, center.y - radius, center.x + radius, center.y + radius, signPaint);
        canvas.drawLine(center.x - radius, center.y + radius, center.x + radius, center.y - radius, signPaint);
    }

    private void drawWinLine(Canvas canvas) {
        float length = winLineLength;

        float a = getMeasuredWidth() / 6f;

        float padding = dpToPx(STROKE_WIDTH);

        switch (winLinePosition) {
            case Constants.NONE:
                break;
            case Constants.ROW_1:
                canvas.drawLine(padding, a, length - padding, a, winLinePaint);
                break;
            case Constants.ROW_2:
                canvas.drawLine(padding, a + (2 * a), length - padding, a + (2 * a), winLinePaint);
                break;
            case Constants.ROW_3:
                canvas.drawLine(padding, a + (4 * a), length - padding, a + (4 * a), winLinePaint);
                break;
            case Constants.COLUMN_1:
                canvas.drawLine(a, padding, a, length - padding, winLinePaint);
                break;
            case Constants.COLUMN_2:
                canvas.drawLine(a + (2 * a), padding, a + (2 * a), length - padding, winLinePaint);
                break;
            case Constants.COLUMN_3:
                canvas.drawLine(a + (4 * a), padding, a + (4 * a), length - padding, winLinePaint);
                break;
            case Constants.DIAGONAL_1:
                canvas.drawLine(padding, padding, length - padding, length - padding, winLinePaint);
                break;
            case Constants.DIAGONAL_2:
                canvas.drawLine(getMeasuredWidth() - padding, padding, padding + getMeasuredWidth()
                        - length, length - padding, winLinePaint);
                break;
        }
    }

    void addSignToBoard(@Constants.Sign int sign, int row, int column) {
        SignData signData = new SignData();
        signData.setSign(sign);
        signData.setRow(row);
        signData.setColumn(column);
        signData.setAnimationFlag(true);

        if (clickAnimator.isRunning()) {
            clickAnimator.end();
        }

        signDataList.add(signData);
        clickAnimator.start();
    }

    void showWinLine(@Constants.WinLinePosition int winLinePosition) {
        this.winLinePosition = winLinePosition;

        winLineAnimator.start();
    }

    void resetBoard() {
        if (!resetAnimator.isRunning()) {
            resetAnimator.start();
        }
    }

    boolean isAlreadyAdded(int row, int column) {
        for (int i = 0; i < signDataList.size(); i++) {
            SignData signData = signDataList.get(i);

            if ((signData.getRow() == row) && (signData.getColumn() == column)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    private float dpToPx(float dp) {
        return TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        float x = e.getX();
        float y = e.getY();

        int row = detectIndexOfPartition(y);
        int column = detectIndexOfPartition(x);

        if ((row != -1) && (column != -1)) {
            onBoardInteractionListener.onBoardClick(BoardView.this, row, column);
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        return false;
    }

    private int detectIndexOfPartition(float value) {
        float maxValue = getMeasuredWidth();
        float totalNumberOfPartitions = 3;

        float lengthOfSinglePartition = maxValue / totalNumberOfPartitions;

        return (int) (value / lengthOfSinglePartition);
    }

    public void setOnBoardInteractionListener(OnBoardInteractionListener onBoardInteractionListener) {
        this.onBoardInteractionListener = onBoardInteractionListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        if (animation == clickAnimator) {
            signRadius = (float) animation.getAnimatedValue();
        } else if (animation == winLineAnimator) {
            winLineLength = (float) animation.getAnimatedValue();
        } else if (animation == resetAnimator) {
            sweeperStartPosition = (float) animation.getAnimatedValue();
        }
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        if (animation == clickAnimator) {
            SignData signData = signDataList.get(signDataList.size() - 1);
            signData.setAnimationFlag(false);
            onBoardInteractionListener.onSignAdded(signData.getSign(), signData.getRow(), signData.getColumn());
            signRadius = 0;
        } else if (animation == resetAnimator) {
            signDataList.clear();
            winLinePosition = Constants.NONE;
            onBoardInteractionListener.onBoardReset();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

    }

    interface OnBoardInteractionListener {

        void onBoardClick(BoardView board, int row, int column);

        void onSignAdded(@Constants.Sign int sign, int row, int column);

        void onBoardReset();
    }

    private class SignData {
        private @Constants.Sign int sign;
        private int row;
        private int column;
        private boolean animationFlag;

        @Constants.Sign int getSign() {
            return sign;
        }

        void setSign(@Constants.Sign int sign) {
            this.sign = sign;
        }

        int getRow() {
            return row;
        }

        void setRow(int row) {
            this.row = row;
        }

        int getColumn() {
            return column;
        }

        void setColumn(int column) {
            this.column = column;
        }

        boolean isAnimationFlag() {
            return animationFlag;
        }

        void setAnimationFlag(boolean animationFlag) {
            this.animationFlag = animationFlag;
        }
    }
}
```

> My Brain class

```
class Brain {
    private static Brain INSTANCE;

    private @Constants.Sign
    int[][] board = new int[3][3];

    private int rowOfResult;
    private int columnOfResult;

    private int depth;

    private @Constants.Sign
    int computerSign;
    private @Constants.Sign
    int playerSign;

    private OnProcessCompleteListener onProcessCompleteListener;

    private static final int HORIZONTAL = 0;
    private static final int VERTICAL = 1;
    private static final int DIAGONAL = 2;

    @IntDef({HORIZONTAL, VERTICAL, DIAGONAL})
    @interface DirectionOfWinLine {

    }

    // References used by isWin function.
    private int[] winSequence = new int[3];
    private int[] row = new int[3];
    private int[] column = new int[3];
    private int[] diagonal1 = new int[3];
    private int[] diagonal2 = new int[3];

    private Brain() {
    }

    static Brain getInstance() {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE = new Brain();
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    void play() {
        if (onProcessCompleteListener == null) {
            return;
        }
        calculateNextMove(computerSign, depth);

        onProcessCompleteListener.onNextMoveCalculated(rowOfResult, columnOfResult);
    }

    private int calculateNextMove(@Constants.Sign int sign, int depth) {

        if (isWin(computerSign, false)) {
            return 10 - depth;
        } else if (isWin(playerSign, false)) {
            return depth - 10;
        }

        if (depth >= 9) {
            return 0;
        }

        List<Integer> scores = new ArrayList<>(), rowIndices = new ArrayList<>(), columnIndices = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if (board[i][j] == Constants.EMPTY) {
                    board[i][j] = sign;
                    scores.add(calculateNextMove(getOppositeSign(sign), depth + 1));
                    rowIndices.add(i);
                    columnIndices.add(j);
                    board[i][j] = Constants.EMPTY;
                }
            }
        }

        if (sign == computerSign) {
            int maxScore = -100;
            for (int i = 0; i < scores.size(); i++) {
                if (scores.get(i) > maxScore) {
                    maxScore = scores.get(i);
                }
            }
            return randomizeScore(maxScore, scores, rowIndices, columnIndices);

        } else {
            int minScore = 100;
            for (int i = 0; i < scores.size(); i++) {
                if (scores.get(i) < minScore) {
                    minScore = scores.get(i);
                }
            }
            return randomizeScore(minScore, scores, rowIndices, columnIndices);
        }
    }

    private int randomizeScore(int score, List<Integer> scores, List<Integer> rowIndices, List<Integer> columnIndices) {
        List<Integer> equalScoreIndices = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < scores.size(); i++) {
            if (scores.get(i) == score) {
                equalScoreIndices.add(i);
            }
        }

        Random rand = new Random();
        int randomIndex = equalScoreIndices.get(rand.nextInt(equalScoreIndices.size()));

        rowOfResult = rowIndices.get(randomIndex);
        columnOfResult = columnIndices.get(randomIndex);

        return score;
    }

    private boolean isWin(@Constants.Sign int sign, boolean notifyWinEnabled) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            winSequence[i] = sign;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {

                if (i == j) {
                    diagonal1[i] = board[i][j];
                }
                if ((i + j) == 2) {
                    diagonal2[i] = board[i][j];
                }

                row[j] = board[i][j];
                column[j] = board[j][i];
            }

            if (isEqual(row, winSequence)) {
                if (notifyWinEnabled) {
                    notifyWin(sign, HORIZONTAL, i + 1);
                }
                return true;
            } else if (isEqual(column, winSequence)) {
                if (notifyWinEnabled) {
                    notifyWin(sign, VERTICAL, i + 1);
                }
                return true;
            }
        }

        if (isEqual(diagonal1, winSequence)) {
            if (notifyWinEnabled) {
                notifyWin(sign, DIAGONAL, 1);
            }
            return true;
        } else if (isEqual(diagonal2, winSequence)) {
            if (notifyWinEnabled) {
                notifyWin(sign, DIAGONAL, 2);
            }
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private boolean isEqual(int[] x, int[] y) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (x[i] != y[i]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    void analyzeBoard() {
        if (onProcessCompleteListener == null) {
            return;
        }

        if ((!isWin(Constants.CIRCLE, true)) && (!isWin(Constants.CROSS, true)) && (depth >= 9)) {
            onProcessCompleteListener.onGameDraw();
        }
    }

    private void notifyWin(@Constants.Sign int sign, @DirectionOfWinLine int direction, int index) {
        if (onProcessCompleteListener == null) {
            return;
        }

        @Constants.WinLinePosition int winLinePosition = Constants.NONE;

        switch (direction) {
            case HORIZONTAL:
                switch (index) {
                    case 1:
                        winLinePosition = Constants.ROW_1;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        winLinePosition = Constants.ROW_2;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        winLinePosition = Constants.ROW_3;
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case VERTICAL:
                switch (index) {
                    case 1:
                        winLinePosition = Constants.COLUMN_1;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        winLinePosition = Constants.COLUMN_2;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        winLinePosition = Constants.COLUMN_3;
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case DIAGONAL:
                switch (index) {
                    case 1:
                        winLinePosition = Constants.DIAGONAL_1;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        winLinePosition = Constants.DIAGONAL_2;
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }

        onProcessCompleteListener.onGameWin(sign, winLinePosition);
    }

    void reset() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                board[i][j] = Constants.EMPTY;
            }
        }
        depth = 0;
    }

    void setComputerSign(int computerSign) {
        this.computerSign = computerSign;
        playerSign = getOppositeSign(computerSign);
    }

    void updateBoard(@Constants.Sign int sign, int row, int column) {
        board[row][column] = sign;
        depth++;
    }

    private @Constants.Sign
    int getOppositeSign(@Constants.Sign int sign) {
        return sign == Constants.CIRCLE ? Constants.CROSS : Constants.CIRCLE;
    }

    void setOnProcessCompleteListener(OnProcessCompleteListener onProcessCompleteListener) {
        this.onProcessCompleteListener = onProcessCompleteListener;
    }

    interface OnProcessCompleteListener {

        void onNextMoveCalculated(int row, int column);

        void onGameWin(@Constants.Sign int sign, @Constants.WinLinePosition int winLinePosition);

        void onGameDraw();
    }

    void destroy() {
        INSTANCE = null;
    }
}
```

I have created github repo for this all code available here

https://github.com/SuperSaiyanGoku3/MyGame

I'm facing some issue in above code

1. The Above code only support hard level (Impossible), how can i create easy medium and hard level in above game algorithm again computer(CPU).
2. how can i set custom icon instead of **O** and **X**
3. how can i set all three game mode randomly in above code, as easy medium and hard level, so when user start the game, cpu will come randomly, wither easy or medium or hard.

Here are some links that i have tried so far but unable to understand how to create easy medium and hard level

- [Learn to create a Tic-Tac-Toe Game for Android](https://medium.com/@ssaurel/learn-to-create-a-tic-tac-toe-game-for-android-82c7bf2369de)
- [Android Studio - JAVA - TIC TAC TOE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36072107/8112541)
- [Android tic tac toe game - logic issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45062904/8112541)
- [Tic-Tac-Toe (TableLayout) Android App](https://medium.com/wiselteach/tic-tac-toe-tablelayout-android-app-androidmonk-a56b9e1c6a15)
- [Tic Tac Toe Game](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23302586/8112541)

If need more information please do let me know. Thanks in advance. Your efforts will be appreciated.

Comment: You do *know* that once you understand the rules  of  *tic-tac-toe*,and seen the possibilities, **ALL** games should end as a draw (unless you make a stupid mistake).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. **Implement difficulty:** For support easy and medium difficulty, I suggest you just use random. You have implemented HARD difficulty, so you just need lesser difficult logic that making "mistakes", and this mistake can be implemented by random.

   ```
    private void calculateNextMoveRandom() {
        Random rand = new Random();

        int randomRow;
        int randomColumn;

        while (true) {
            randomRow = rand.nextInt(3);
            randomColumn = rand.nextInt(3);

            if (Constants.EMPTY == board[randomRow][randomColumn]) {
                rowOfResult = randomRow;
                columnOfResult = randomColumn;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
   ```

2. **Bitmap marker:** You can use `BitmapFactory.decodeResource()` to draw bitmap on screen.

```
    private void drawCircle(Canvas canvas, PointF center, boolean animationFlag) {
        int iconSize = (int) LayoutUtil.getPixelFromDp(MARKER_SIZE, getContext());
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.android);
        Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, iconSize, iconSize, true);
        canvas.drawBitmap(scaled, center.x - (iconSize >> 1), center.y - (iconSize >> 1), signPaint);
    }
```

3. **Random difficulty:** Just use random to set difficulty.

```
    brain.setDifficulty(new Random().nextInt(3));
```

Here is my pull request: (Fallen link) 
https://github.com/SuperSaiyanGoku3/MyGame/pull/1

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a [minimax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax) strategy to play tic-tac-toe, you can have multiple switch cases that correspond to different difficulty levels in the game. The most naive method of doing this is by putting different depth thresholds in the minimax tree. For example, you can expand the minimax game tree until only depth 2 (assuming for a 3*3 tic-tac-toe) for easy level and say until the end of the search tree for the highest difficulty level. You can set this threshold depending on the board size and the difficulty level expected.

Another way of implementing difficulty levels is by implementing different heuristic functions to calculate the board score (a goodness measure to the current state of the board). You can have your heuristic function that evaluates the individual row/column/diagonal score based on the number of cells that you occupy in that row/column/diagonal. For example, if the number of cells occupied is 1, then score = x (x can be any arbitrary number). If the number of cells occupied is 2, then score = x^2 and if it is 3, then score = x^3. Then multiply all individual line scores to get a measure of goodness (or you can think of this as a winning probability) in each row, column or diagonal. You can calculate a similar score for your opponent and then take a difference to get a board score. Thus the idea is to implement different ways of evaluating current board states by designing different variations of the heuristic function for each difficulty level. A bad heuristic function would work as an easy level since it will lose a lot of games whereas a properly designed heuristic will have a no-lose policy (it will end up winning or drawing the game).

In order to randomly choose a difficulty level at each run of the game, you can use a random number generator to pick a difficulty level. You can assign '0' as easy, '1' as medium and '2' as hard. You can use the following java function to generate an integer between 0 and (n-1)

`int random = Random.nextInt(n)`

Answer (score 0):

[Complete Tic Tac Toe with "n x n matrix"](https://github.com/akshaytilekar7/TicTacToe)

Basic ideas is that we just have to check if column / row / diagonal elements are same.
code written in C#, with basic unit test.